# Programmatically (.NET) renaming an Azure File or Directory using File (not Blob) Storage

Tags: .net, azure

I've read that files and directories created using Azure *file* storage can be renamed programmatically, but cannot find a way to do that using the .NET Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage assembly (I am using v4.3.).  I know that blobs cannot be renamed, but files using file storage supposedly can.  For reference I'm including the code snippet below.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("mycredentials");

CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

CloudFileShare fileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference("myfileshare");

fileShare.CreateIfNotExists();

CloudFileDirectory rootDir = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();

CloudFileDirectory directory = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("mydirectory");

// The Name property of directory is read-only, and can't find a Rename method
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Till date, there is no rename operation supported on Azure and there might be reasons behind that, however, the alternative is to create a copy with new name and deleting old name. Even amazon s3 does not support renaming. The reason could be indexing and caching done at many levels, which cannot be renamed easily so they have not included as a core feature.

Comment: Thank you.  One of the problems with doing this is the amount of overhead in renaming a directory using File storage; I would need to delete and re-create every file and directory within the directory hierarchy of the directory being renamed, which could be many files and sub-directories.  It seems somewhat absurd that by now, Azure hasn't come up with a way to do that efficiently.