# How to rename or copy file from azure storage using java file system sdk

Tags: java, file, azure, rename

How to rename or copy file from azure storage using java file system sdk
Is there any way to rename or copy file stored in azurestorage from azurestorage.jar for java if so pls help us.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the file is on the file share mounted in the system, you can use [Files.copy(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) to copy file

```
Path sourcePath = new File("path/to/source/file").toPath();
Path targetPath = new File("path/to/target/file").toPath();
Files.copy(sourcePath, targetPath);
```

Note that the code will download the source file to local host, then upload to the azure storage service.

If you want to avoid download and upload, use [azure storage rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-file) to copy file. If you don't want to deal with rest api directly, use [azure-sdk-for-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/azure-storage-file-share_12.8.0/sdk/storage/azure-storage-file-share) or similar SDKs for python and C#.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66774796/12066108 shows how to copy file with azure-sdk-for-java library.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CloudFile.startCopy(source)` to rename and copy blob files. And here is the complete code.

```
package nau.edu.cn.steven;

import com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CopyStatus;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CloudFile;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CloudFileClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CloudFileDirectory;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CloudFileShare;

public class AzureCopyFile {

        // Connection string
        public static final String storageConnectionString =
    "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;"
    + "AccountName=your_account_name;"
    + "AccountKey= your_account_key";

        public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            try {

                CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
                CloudFileClient fileClient = account.createCloudFileClient();

                // Get a reference to the file share
                CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference("sampleshare");

                if(share.createIfNotExists()) {
                    System.out.println("New share created");
                }

                // Get a reference to the root directory for the share for example
                CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();

                // Old file
                CloudFile oldCloudFile = rootDir.getFileReference("Readme.txt");
                // New file
                CloudFile newCloudFile = rootDir.getFileReference("Readme2.txt");
                // Start copy
                newCloudFile.startCopy(oldCloudFile.getUri());

                // Exit until copy finished
                while(true) {
                    if(newCloudFile.getCopyState().getStatus() != CopyStatus.PENDING) {
                        break;
                    }

                    // Sleep for a second maybe
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.print("Exception encountered: ");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: We are not using blob is their any other way to achieve rename or copy from CloudFile cloudFile = sampleDir.getFileReference("filename");

Comment: Thanks steven i am able to copy using startCopy(cloudfile.getUri); Is there any way to rename file in azure storage using java if it is available please suggest me.

Comment: Is their any way to track the copy operation in azure file system in azure drive using java

Comment: You could refer to [Track blob copy progress](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/copy-blobs-with-startcopyfromblob-and-track-its-progression-using-copystate/), there is a function there called **PrintStatus** which is want you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to the javadocs for the class [`CloudFile`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/file/CloudFile.html) of Azure File Storage, there is no rename operation supported natively for File Storage, even for Blob Storage.

If you want to do the rename action, you need to perform 2 steps include copy a file with a new name and delete the file with old name.

There are two threads below separately from SO & MSDN.

1. [Programmatically (.NET) renaming an Azure File or Directory using File (not Blob) Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816118/Programmatically%20(.NET)%20renaming%20an%20Azure%20File%20or%20Directory%20using%20File%20(not%20Blob)%20Storage/28816440), that's the same for using Java.
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/04c415fb-cc1a-4270-986b-03a68b05aa81/renaming-files-in-blobs-storage?forum=windowsazuredata.

As @Steven said, the copy operation is supported via the function `startCopy` for a new file reference.