# How to copy Azure storage files/directories using java azure-storage-file-datalake

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-storage-files

I use [azure-storage-file-datalake](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-file-datalake/12.2.0) for java to make file system operations on my Azure storage account,  I can open files, delete, and even rename/move files or directories.

I can't find any way to copy files/folder to other location.

That's how I rename/move files/directories:

```
    DataLakeServiceClient storageClient = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder().endpoint(endpoint).credential(credential).buildClient();
    DataLakeFileSystemClient dataLakeFileSystemClient = storageClient.getFileSystemClient("storage");
    DataLakeFileClient fileClient = dataLakeFileSystemClient.getFileClient("src/path");
    fileClient.rename("storage", "dest/path");
```

Is there any other method I can use to copy files or directories using the `azure-storage-file-datalake` SDK or even the `azure-storage-blob` SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a method to copy blobs(files) within the same storage account using `com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient`.

using [`beginCopy`](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0/com/azure/storage/blob/specialized/BlobClientBase.html#beginCopy-java.lang.String-java.time.Duration-) method as follows:

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint(spnEndpoint).credential(credential).buildClient();
BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient =  blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("containerName");
BlobClient dst = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient("destination/blob");
BlobClient src = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient("src/blob");
dst.beginCopy(src.getBlobUrl(), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [azure-sdk-for-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/azure-storage-file-share_12.8.0/sdk/storage/azure-storage-file-share/#copy-a-file) to copy file

```
String CONNECT_STRING = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<account-name>;AccountKey=<account key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
String SHARE_NAME = "share-name";

ShareFileClient client = new ShareFileClientBuilder()
        .connectionString(CONNECT_STRING)
        .shareName(SHARE_NAME)
        .resourcePath("path/to/target/file.txt")
        .buildFileClient();

String srcFile = "https://<account-name>.file.core.windows.net/share-name/path/to/source/file.txt";
SyncPoller<ShareFileCopyInfo, Void> poller = client.beginCopy(srcFile, null, Duration.ofSeconds(2));
final PollResponse<ShareFileCopyInfo> pollResponse = poller.poll();
final ShareFileCopyInfo value = pollResponse.getValue();
System.out.printf("Copy source: %s. Status: %s.%n", value.getCopySourceUrl(), value.getCopyStatus());
```

The above example uses connect string to create file client, you can also use SAS token to create file client, see java doc [ShareFileClientBuilder](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-file-share/12.8.0/com/azure/storage/file/share/ShareFileClientBuilder.html) for details. Both connect string and/or SAS token are available on your storage account page in azure portal.

Answer (score -1):

**`azure-storage-file-datalake:`**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.file.datalake.datalakedirectoryclient.rename?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_storage_file_datalake_DataLakeDirectoryClient_rename_java_lang_String_java_lang_String_

---

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.file.datalake.datalakefileclient.rename?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_storage_file_datalake_DataLakeFileClient_rename_java_lang_String_java_lang_String_

**`azure-storage-blob`**

This seems not to have a method to achieve this.

Comment: I didn't mean to use the `rename` method exactly to copy files. I am looking for any other method to use to copy files/folders in these java clients. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It isn't clear what this answer is trying to say. What are you intending to illustrate with the two references to the documentation?